# Check if php insert was successful when using AngularJS $http

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

I'm a beginner when it comes to AngularJS but I have just figured out how to pass POST data using the `$http` service to a PHP file to insert to my database.

**This is my add.php file. It displays my form and has the insert code block at the bottom:**

```
<h2>Add Car</h2>
<div ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <form method="POST">
        <label>Make:</label>
        <select ng-model="car.make">
            <option>Make 1</option>
            <option>Make 2</option>
            <option>Make 3</option>
        </select>
        <label>Model:</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="car.model">
        <input type="submit" ng-click="addCar(car)">
    </form>

    <pre>
        {{message}}
    </pre>
</div>


<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$make = $data->make;
$model = $data->model;

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO cars (model, make) VALUES(?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $model);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $make);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

**This is my controller:**

```
app.controller('formCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.addCar = function (car) {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'tools/add.php',
            data: car,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        })
        .then(function (response) {
           $scope.message = "great!"; 
        });
    }
});
```

Now is there anyway to check to see if the insert was successful? I know you can use the `rowCount()` function to check on the PHP side and then set your message to either be an error or a successful insert, but I'd like to know if there's anyway for my JS to know whether a row was actually inserted or not.

Comment: You'll have to send it as a response from the server-side code, no other way.

Comment: Send success response from `php` end and handle the same in controller..

Comment: Your PHP file should check if everything is okay and then print a JSON with the result. For example ``{"status":"ok"}`` or ``{"status":"error"}``. In angular, you can then get this data by catching the promise, which is returned by the $http service (like in your code). The response then contains an object data, which is exactly the response from the server (``response.data.status`` is either ``ok`` or ``error``). You could also send another HTTP status code (200 vs. e.g. 400 or 500). Then you can catch the success case in the first argument function of then, and the error in the 2nd.

Comment: Would adding something like `if ($stmt->rowCount()) { $status = json_encode('{"status" : 1}'); } else { $status = json_encode('{"status" : 0}');}` be a waste of time vs. echoing it out into a page and then using another ajax call to get the json? Is there a better way after I encode the json that I could just pass the data back to my JS without making another call? - I apologize in advance for my ignorance, very new to the JS world, especially Angular.

Comment: You have one PHP page which does all the stuff: The Insertion into the DB and the check if it is in the DB. If it is in there, you return status 1 and if not you return status 0. Angular is waiting until you get the final response of PHP (the page is fully loaded). So, you do not have to make another call for that (of course, you could do that..). If you want to pass the inserted data back to angular, you just create an extended version of the return object. Something like: ``{"status":1,"data":[{"model":"Audi"},{....}]}`` or any other data structure you have in PHP. (use json_encode for that)

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I ended up separating my PHP from my HTML and after getting the response I did a simple echo to the page just like you said and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if insert was successful:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) { 
   // It worked
} else {
   // It didn't
}
```

Why not add something like `die('Not successful');` in PHP. Then get angular to check if an error message was provided:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'tools/add.php',
    data: car,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
})
.then(function (response) { 
    if(!response) {
         // Success
         $scope.message = "great!"; 
    } else {
         // Fail
         alert(response);
    }
});
```

Dont forget you can also use `.success()` and `.error()` in Angular too.

One final thing! I've found that keeping my JSON request files separate to partials has made everything easier and manageable. The above solution won't work as there is HTML data sent before it gets to the JSON stuff!